# Print all lines between "start" and "end" if and only if the target pattern "target" occurs between "start" and "end"

Tags: linux

I would like to use linux shell to search all files in a directory and view the lines in any file which have a target pattern bounded between known start and end patterns. For example, given

```
blah blah
blah blah blah
blah start blah
blah
target
blah blah
end blah
blah 
blah
```

I would like to return

```
blah start blah
blah
target
blah blah
end blah
```

I have tried

```
sed -n '/start/,/end/{/target/p}' file.txt
```

which only searches one file and doesn't appear to print the entire interval from start to end. I failed with grep and awk (probably reflecting my inexperience).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to do this. Without installing some additional software I would suggest using Perl, as it is probably already installed on your system.

```
perl -0ne 'print "$&\n" while /^[^\r\n]*?start.*?target.*?end.*?$/gms' file.txt
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ofhh2M/1) here.

The '-0' command line switch basically makes perl to read your whole text file as a single line (it sets the line separator to a character with code 0, instead of normal '\n').

With the '-n' switch perl executes the expression, specified with '-e' switch for each line of the input, and do not print the result by default.

So, this one-liner works like this pseudo-code:

```
set line separator to byte 0, in practice gobble the whole text file at once;
while (there are some lines to read from the input) {
   read the line;
   while (the line matches the regex /^[^\r\n]*?start.*?target.*?end.*?$/ms) {
      print the whole match, followed by "\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much. It does indeed seem to work for the example above. It does not however appear to correctly return ALL such intervals, assuming there are multiple such intervals in an individual text file. Looks like it maybe catches only the first. I would help to understand the syntax of your perl call. (Smaller issue: it doesn't recursively check - or at least batch check - a bunch of text files.).

Comment: I have updated the answer so that it will catch multiple intervals. I only added '?' in two places to make the regex to look for a minimum match, not the maximum one.